# tables available in Spark-SQL CLI are not available over thriftserver

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to expose my spark-sql tables over JDBC via thriftserver but even though it looks like i've successfully connected, its not working. Here's what I've tried so far.

**database setup:**

- in pyspark I loaded a parquet file, created a temp view as `tableX`
- performed a `.saveAsTable` as `hive_tableX`
- then I queried that table: `spark.sql("SELECT * FROM hive_tableX LIMIT 1").show()` which returned some data
- at this point, my code is saving table information to the hivestore, right?

**querying from spark-sql:**

- I then ran `spark-sql` and the spark sql shell started up
- `USE default`
- `show tables;` --> i see my table in there, `hive_tableX`
- `SELECT * FROM hive_tableX LIMIT 1` and I see some successful results.
- thus, I believe it is now verified that my table has saved in the hive metastore, right?

**then I turn on thriftserver**

- `./sbin/start-thriftserver.sh`

**next, I turn on beeline so I can test the thriftserver connection**

- `!connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000` (and enter username and password)
- then I select the default db: `use default;`
- and `show tables;` --> there's nothing there.

***So, where are my tables? is beeline or thrift pointing to a different warehouse or something?***

**Edit:** I think my thriftserver isn't using the right warehouse directory, so I'm trying to start it with a config option:

- **[still nothing]** sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --hiveconf spark.sql.warehouse.dir=/code/spark/thrift/spark-warehouse
- **[still nothing]** sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir=/code/spark/thrift/spark-warehouse

**Edit:** starting it in the same physical directory as where the wherehouse was created seems to do the trick. Although, I don't know how to programmatically set the path to something else and start it elsewhere.

Comment: BTW, you can directly do select/create on parquet `SELECT * FROM parquet.\`parquet/file/location\` LIMIT 1`.

Comment: try to authenticate to thrift server same user with whom spark-shell/sql started. If user is **spark** then connection string is `!connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000 spark spark`

Comment: The problem ended up being that I was starting the thrift server in a different directory than where the spark warehouse was located. Now I need to know how to actually pass that path in rather than physically being in that directory

Comment: you can **configure derby in Server mode** or **use mysql database** as metastore for both shell and thrift server. So, that meta data will be share for both of them without starting from location. Right now meta file will be written to the local directory(derby embeded mode - it's default) where thrift or shell is started and it cannot be shared when we start them from diff directory.

Answer (score 0):

the solution to this particular problem was that I was starting thrift from a different directory than the `spark-wherehouse` and `metastore_db` were located.

Once I started it from the correct directory, it worked as expected and my tables were now available.

Comment: Using **remote database for meta store** is another solution to it. I could think of one issue with schema in local file is, by any chance if the meta store file is corrupted we'll loose entire schema of spark tables.